# What's the right way to remove multiple indices for a QStandardItemModel?

Tags: qt, model, qt4

I was trying to remove all selected indices of a QTableView,

Now I use:

```
foreach (const QModelIndex & idx, model->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
{
    model->removeRow (idx.row()); // Obviously bug
}
```

There's a obvious problem that once you remove the row, the row id is invalidated, w

As there's no function that takes directly the index (or does the index act like a iterator that will get invalidated when data changed?), I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `QPersistanceModelIndex` class which keeps valid state of index. I tried and it seems to be working.

```
QList<QPersistentModelIndex> indexes;

foreach (const QModelIndex &i, ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
    indexes << i;

foreach (const QPersistentModelIndex &i, indexes)
    ui->tableView->model()->removeRow(i.row());
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: What if the row number aren't consecutive?

Comment: @warl0ck initially I haven't understood your question. I am sorry about it. Now I updated answer, please check it.