# What's the right way to remove multiple items from a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt4

QTableWidget is model-less, and I run into [similar situations to this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969509/whats-the-right-way-to-remove-multiple-indices-for-a-qstandarditemmodel) there is no functions to erase multiple rows simultaneously, only a:

`void QTableWidget::removeRow ( int row )`

And there's no persistent index I think, what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

You should get a list of selected items and then iterate through each of them and delete the pointer to each item. For example:

```
foreach(QTableWidgetItem * item, tableWidget.selectedItems())
{
    delete item;
}
```

It's safe to delete the pointer directly as I've used this method to delete similar items from QTreeWidgets and QListWidgets.

Hope this helps.